# How to get the last inserted item from dynamodb using boto3?

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, boto3

i have below items in my dynamodb

```
entry    timestamp                        status    key
ent1     Fri Dec 04 11:26:17 EST 2020     Success   101
ent2     Fri Dec 04 11:26:18 EST 2020     Failure   102
ent3     Fri Dec 04 11:26:19 EST 2020     Success   101
```

here i need to fetch only the last inserted status = Success , ie based on the latest time stamp- ent3

#Expected

```
ent3     Fri Dec 04 11:26:19 EST 2020     Success   101
```

i didn't see the result return when using below code

```
response=table.query(KeyConditionExpression= Key('key').eq('101'),
FilterExpression=Attr('status').eq('Success'))
```

so how can filter/fetch for the last inserted item from the db?

THanks

Comment: Which attributes are your primary key?  Are you using a sort key and partition key?  It's not obvious from the question.   The key attribute seems like a good candidate,  but is not unique in your example

Comment: Also, you say you don't see the result return.  Do you get anything back at all?

Answer (score 1):

You can add a [Global Secondary Index](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/GSI.html) (GSI) with `status` as the partition key and `timestamp` as the sort key, then query that GSI with `Limit=1` to get the item with the latest timestamp. Add `ScanIndexForward=false` to your query if you want the earliest timestamp.

Comment: Great thought but keep in mind that adding a GSI adds an immediate extra cost. When you add a GSI what happens behind the scenes is that your table is duplicated. The new table is kept in sync with the original table the only difference is the new table's partition key is the GSI. Example: table1 PK is key table2 (hidden table) PK is status.

Comment: @Mickers Yes, though it depends on which attributes are [projected](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/bp-indexes-general.html#bp-indexes-general-projections) into the index but, yes, it's good to clarify that there are additional costs for secondary indexes. There's a trade-off here vs. scanning the entire table to filter on the items you want, that's both slower and itself consumes WCU.

Answer (score 0):

Try updating your code to follow this format:

```
table.query(
  KeyConditionExpression='#a = :a',
  ExpressionAttributeValues={
    ':a': '101',
    ':b': 'Success'
  },
  ExpressionAttributeNames={
    '#a': 'key',
    '#b': 'status'
  },
  FilterExpression='#a = :a AND #b= :b'
)
```

I've not used the helpers you've used above as it's easier and more dynamic to pass your equations as string arguments. You can also replace 'a' with a more meaningful name so it's easier to read.

EDIT: I've mixed two examples together so this code probably won't work as is but the point was to give an example of another way to accomplish your goal.

Answer (score 0):

if you need last data in specific partition like ent3 in entry partition key ,
you can try something like that

```
 response = dynamodb_client.query(TableName='TableName',
 KeyConditionExpression='#id =:id',
 ExpressionAttributeValues={
 ':id': {'S': 'ent3'}
 },
 ExpressionAttributeNames = {
 '#id':'entry'
 },
 Limit=1,ScanIndexForward=False)
 print(response['Items'])
```