# How to get the last inserted item from dynamodb, after that create new item using Aws appsync

Tags: amazon-web-services, graphql, amazon-dynamodb, aws-appsync

I am using aws appsync and dynomoDB. I have a table called Payment and I want to create each item with an unique sequential number that is `PaymentNo`.

If we want to achive this, we have to get last inserted item in order to update the `PaymentNO` count. Actually, I don't know, "how to get the last inserted item from table in the same resolver?

could anyone help me to write a resolver for this ?

##### schema

```
type Payment @model(subscriptions: null) {
    id: ID!
    paid_amount: Float
    paid_date: AWSDate
    description: String
    PaymentNO: Int
}
```

##### My request resolver

```
## [Start] Set default values. **
$util.qr($context.args.input.put("id", $util.defaultIfNull($ctx.args.input.id, $util.autoId())))
#set( $createdAt = $util.time.nowISO8601() )

## Automatically set the createdAt timestamp. **
$util.qr($context.args.input.put("createdAt", $util.defaultIfNull($ctx.args.input.createdAt, $createdAt)))

## Automatically set the updatedAt timestamp. **
$util.qr($context.args.input.put("updatedAt", $util.defaultIfNull($ctx.args.input.updatedAt, $createdAt)))
## [End] Set default values. **

## [Start] Prepare DynamoDB PutItem Request. **
$util.qr($context.args.input.put("__typename", "FeePayment"))
#if( $modelObjectKey )
  #set( $condition = {
  "expression": "",
  "expressionNames": {},
  "expressionValues": {}
} )
  #foreach( $entry in $modelObjectKey.entrySet() )
    #if( $velocityCount == 1 )
      $util.qr($condition.put("expression", "attribute_not_exists(#keyCondition$velocityCount)"))
    #else
      $util.qr($condition.put("expression", "$condition.expression AND attribute_not_exists(#keyCondition$velocityCount)"))
    #end
    $util.qr($condition.expressionNames.put("#keyCondition$velocityCount", "$entry.key"))
  #end
#else
  #set( $condition = {
  "expression": "attribute_not_exists(#id)",
  "expressionNames": {
      "#id": "id"
  },
  "expressionValues": {}
} )
#end
#if( $context.args.condition )
  #set( $condition.expressionValues = {} )
  #set( $conditionFilterExpressions = $util.parseJson($util.transform.toDynamoDBConditionExpression($context.args.condition)) )
  $util.qr($condition.put("expression", "($condition.expression) AND $conditionFilterExpressions.expression"))
  $util.qr($condition.expressionNames.putAll($conditionFilterExpressions.expressionNames))
  $util.qr($condition.expressionValues.putAll($conditionFilterExpressions.expressionValues))
#end
#if( $condition.expressionValues && $condition.expressionValues.size() == 0 )
  #set( $condition = {
  "expression": $condition.expression,
  "expressionNames": $condition.expressionNames
} )
#end
{
  "version": "2018-05-29",
  "operation": "PutItem",
  "key": #if( $modelObjectKey ) $util.toJson($modelObjectKey) #else {
  "id":   $util.dynamodb.toDynamoDBJson($ctx.args.input.id)
} #end,
  "attributeValues": $util.dynamodb.toMapValuesJson($context.args.input),
  "condition": $util.toJson($condition)
}
## [End] Prepare DynamoDB PutItem Request. **
```

##### response resolver

```
#if( $ctx.error )
$util.error($ctx.error.message, $ctx.error.type)
#else
$util.toJson($ctx.result)
#end
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get the last inserted item from dynamodb using boto3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65822834/how-to-get-the-last-inserted-item-from-dynamodb-using-boto3)

Comment: Sorry no, they are using python. But, I am using AWS appsync

Comment: You need to do 2 things: (1) figure out what DynamoDB query will return the last item
and (2) add the query into the AppSync VTL resolver.  #1 is a DynamoDB table design question, which  @shimo's link helpfully addresses.
Would need to know the table design (keys, indexes, columns) in order to help.